# How can I import an HTML file using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to import an HTML file and use it as a template for a UI Element, but apparently I cannot configure webpack properly so it can read it.

For now I've got an error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|
|     <section id='hero'>
 @ ./src/js/components/landing/landing-component.js 5:0-59
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Webpack Configuration

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    removeComments: true,
                }
            },
]
```

The way I am trying to import it

```
import LandingTemplate from './landing-template.html'
```

Comment: HTML Loader - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/

Comment: Yes, I know. I’m actually using it right now but it doesn’t seem to handle my file. The error you can see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my node_modules and `npm install` installed everything back and it helped